# Collaborative Filtering - R

Tags: r, collaborative-filtering, pearson-correlation

I need to get the top 5 movies recommended for Victoria, by using a weighted average of every other critic's rankings. 
I was only able to do it in Excel but I need to translate into R.
the formula for getting the value is:

Victoria's mean + (Σ(other critic grade - other critic avg grade) * pearson correlation) / Σ Absolute weighted pearson value - 1 (which is victoria's)

to better illustrate
for the movie The.Matrix here's is what the result should be

John vote = 4

John Average = 3,0714

John pearson cor = 0,27709796

Formula = (4-3,07) * 0,27709796 / 6,9280 (sum of abs weighted values)

**(How do I create this formula in R ???) If only I could figure this out, maybe I could do the rest**

After doing this for everyone you add 3,1538 (Victoria's Avg) which should yield 
3,791701302

I need to do it for all the movies Victorias hasn't watched and these should be the results

```
3.7917013044215, 'The Matrix'
3.50776533175371, 'Forrest Gump'  
3.33118834864677, 'The Sixth Sense'
3.11491825315719, 'Shakespeare in Love'
2.9124513228665, 'Blade Runner'
```

Here's The Matrix version on Excel:

[image: Excel's version of the formula for the movie The Matrix]

So far this is my code:

```
cr2<-t(cr[,2:21]) 
colnames(cr2)<-cr[,1] 
cr2<-as.data.frame(cr2)    
cr$Mean <- rowMeans(cr[,2:20], na.rm = TRUE)
cr$Pearson <- cor(cr2[,1:20], cr2[15], use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
cr$PearsonABS <- abs(cor(cr2[,1:20], cr2[15], use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))
x <- sum(cr$PearsonABS) - 1
```

I did it in a very crap way (manually)

```
g <- cr[15,22]

#Forrest Gump
fg = cr[,4] - cr[, 22]
fga = fg * cr[,23]
fgb = fga / x 
fgc = sum(fgb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(fgc)

#The Shawshank Redemption
sr = cr[,5] - cr[, 22]
sra = sr * cr[,23]
srb = sra / x 
src = sum(srb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(src)

#Saving Private Ryan
sp = cr[,9] - cr[, 22]
spa = sp * cr[,23]
spb = spa / x 
spc = sum(spb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(spc)

#Shakespeare in Love
sl = cr[,12] - cr[, 22]
sla = sl * cr[,23]
slb = sla / x 
slc = sum(slb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(slc)

#Blade Runner
br = cr[,15] - cr[, 22]
bra = br * cr[,23]
brb = bra / x 
brc = sum(brb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(brc)

#The Matrix
tm = cr[,17] - cr[, 22]
tma = tm * cr[,23]
tmb = tma / x 
tmc = sum(tmb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(tmc)

#The Sixth Sense
ts = cr[,19] - cr[, 22]
tsa = ts * cr[,23]
tsb = tsa / x 
tsc = sum(tsb, na.rm = TRUE) + g
print(tsc)

my_list <- c(fgc, src, spc, slc, brc, tmc, tsc)
head(sort(my_list, decreasing=TRUE), 5)
```

Here's the dput()

```
dput(cr)
structure(list(User = structure(c(8L, 10L, 2L, 17L, 11L, 1L, 
18L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 14L, 13L, 4L, 20L, 6L, 16L, 12L, 15L, 19L
), .Label = c("Ana", "Anton", "Bernard", "Carles", "Chris", "Ivan", 
"Jim", "John", "Marc", "Maria", "Martina", "Nadia", "Nerea", 
"Nuria", "Oriol", "Rachel", "Roger", "Sergi", "Valery", "Victoria"
), class = "factor"), Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope = c(1L, 5L, NA, 
NA, 4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 
1L), Star.Wars.VI...Return.of.the.Jedi = c(5L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
4L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 5L, 1L, 2L), 
    Forrest.Gump = c(2L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
    5L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L), The.Shawshank.Redemption = c(NA, 
    2L, 5L, NA, 1L, 4L, 1L, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5L, NA, 4L), The.Silence.of.the.Lambs = c(4L, 4L, 2L, 
    NA, 4L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    NA, 5L), Gladiator = c(4L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA), Toy.Story = c(2L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, NA, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), Saving.Private.Ryan = c(2L, NA, NA, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 5L, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 
    3L), Pulp.Fiction = c(NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
    4L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L), Stand.by.Me = c(3L, 
    4L, 1L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
    NA, NA, 3L, 2L), Shakespeare.in.Love = c(2L, 3L, NA, NA, 
    5L, 5L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, NA, 3L, 
    1L), Total.Recall = c(NA, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 
    NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), Independence.Day = c(5L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Blade.Runner = c(2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 
    3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 5L), 
    Groundhog.Day = c(NA, 2L, 1L, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, 
    NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 5L), The.Matrix = c(4L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, 
    4L, NA, 2L, 4L), Schindler.s.List = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
    NA, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L
    ), The.Sixth.Sense = c(5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 
    1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L), Raiders.of.the.Lost.Ark = c(NA, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
    NA, 2L, NA, 3L), Babe = c(NA, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 
    5L, NA, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, NA), Mean = c(3.07142857142857, 
    2.78571428571429, 2.46153846153846, 2.69230769230769, 3.21428571428571, 
    3.07142857142857, 2.54545454545455, 2.83333333333333, 3.15384615384615, 
    3.18181818181818, 2.81818181818182, 2.72727272727273, 3.7, 
    2.63636363636364, 3.15384615384615, 2.83333333333333, 2.8, 
    3.07692307692308, 2.5, 3.0625), Pearson = structure(c(0.277097961607667, 
    0.492592183071889, -0.184664098655286, -0.306988756155365, 
    0.047716527859489, 0.597614304667197, 0.0363696483726654, 
    0.0793422835603058, -0.444514447822542, -0.344265186329548, 
    -0.186499664263607, 0.365148371670111, 0.205737799949456, 
    0.427324672683063, 1, -0.732776720760177, 0.944911182523068, 
    -0.587378478571482, 0.578979445733232, -0.0881134221062802
    ), .Dim = c(20L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("John", "Maria", 
    "Anton", "Roger", "Martina", "Ana", "Sergi", "Marc", "Jim", 
    "Chris", "Bernard", "Nuria", "Nerea", "Carles", "Victoria", 
    "Ivan", "Rachel", "Nadia", "Oriol", "Valery"), "Victoria")), 
    PearsonABS = structure(c(0.277097961607667, 0.492592183071889, 
    0.184664098655286, 0.306988756155365, 0.047716527859489, 
    0.597614304667197, 0.0363696483726654, 0.0793422835603058, 
    0.444514447822542, 0.344265186329548, 0.186499664263607, 
    0.365148371670111, 0.205737799949456, 0.427324672683063, 
    1, 0.732776720760177, 0.944911182523068, 0.587378478571482, 
    0.578979445733232, 0.0881134221062802), .Dim = c(20L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("John", "Maria", "Anton", "Roger", "Martina", "Ana", 
        "Sergi", "Marc", "Jim", "Chris", "Bernard", "Nuria", 
        "Nerea", "Carles", "Victoria", "Ivan", "Rachel", "Nadia", 
        "Oriol", "Valery"), "Victoria"))), .Names = c("User", 
"Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope", "Star.Wars.VI...Return.of.the.Jedi", 
"Forrest.Gump", "The.Shawshank.Redemption", "The.Silence.of.the.Lambs", 
"Gladiator", "Toy.Story", "Saving.Private.Ryan", "Pulp.Fiction", 
"Stand.by.Me", "Shakespeare.in.Love", "Total.Recall", "Independence.Day", 
"Blade.Runner", "Groundhog.Day", "The.Matrix", "Schindler.s.List", 
"The.Sixth.Sense", "Raiders.of.the.Lost.Ark", "Babe", "Mean", 
"Pearson", "PearsonABS"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I hope I was clear in trying to explain it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: To be clear, you want to do this calculation for every movie, but just for Victoria, or for every movie and for every critic? EDIT: sorry missed the line about doing it for every movie Victoria hasn't watched

Comment: I did it manually (you can see it above) but I'm really not happy about it, I wish I could do it some other way

Comment: But do you want to do it another way because you need to do it for every movie, or for every person? Or just to learn to automate it?

Comment: I need it automated, I need to know how to detect the movies that Victoria hasn't watched and then run the formulas to give the result that I need.
I was able to do it manually because the dataset is pretty small, but I will need to do the same for a much bigger dataset as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I hope you can follow this, I will try to give enough explanation. The goal is to write a function that can wrap up your manual calculations and make it easy to run many times.

### Tidying

First we want to make the data tidy, so it is easier to work with. This means making each column a variable, so no having film ratings across multiple columns. See [more about tidy data here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). We're going to use the `tidyverse` package to do this.

1. Drop the mean and pearson columns with `select`. We will want to be able to calculate them differently depending on which user we are looking at, and they are also stored weirdly in your `dput` as lists.
2. Use `gather` to take all the film columns and put the film names into one column and the ratings into another.
3. Rename `User` to be lowercase for consistency
4. Use `group_by` and `mutate` to make a mean rating for each user. `na.rm = TRUE` means that `mean` will ignore all the `NA` values when calculating.

which looks like this. See the data is now tidy, with just four columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
tidy_cr <- cr %>%
  select(-Mean, -Pearson, -PearsonABS) %>%
  gather("film", "rating", -User) %>%
  rename(user = User) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 400 x 4
   user    film                      rating  mean
   <fct>   <chr>                      <int> <dbl>
 1 John    Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      1  3.07
 2 Maria   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      5  2.79
 3 Anton   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope     NA  2.46
 4 Roger   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope     NA  2.69
 5 Martina Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      4  3.21
 6 Ana     Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      2  3.07
 7 Sergi   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope     NA  2.55
 8 Marc    Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      4  2.83
 9 Jim     Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      5  3.15
10 Chris   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      4  3.18
# ... with 390 more rows
```

### Victoria example

This is a step by step to show you the output at each stage, using Victoria as our example. First, we want to find out which films Victoria hasn't seen. We do this by `filter`ing down to the rows which have Victoria in the `user` column and `NA` rating, and then pulling out the `film` column.

```
v_films_not_seen <- tidy_cr %>%
  filter(user == "Victoria" & is.na(rating)) %>%
  extract2("film")
[1] "Forrest.Gump"             "The.Shawshank.Redemption" "Saving.Private.Ryan"     
[4] "Shakespeare.in.Love"      "Blade.Runner"             "The.Matrix"              
[7] "The.Sixth.Sense"
```

Then, we want to pull out Victoria's ratings so we can compute the correlation coefficients and her specific mean. We reduce to rows with Victoria again and now pull out the `rating` column.

```
v_persons_ratings <- tidy_cr %>%
  filter(user == "Victoria") %>%
  extract2("rating")
 [1]  4  4 NA NA  5  5  2 NA  3  5 NA  1  3 NA  2 NA  3 NA  3  1
```

Now we want to compute the correlations. We first `group_by` user, so this calculation will be done per-user. Then we use `mutate` and `cor` to calculate the correlation between each user's ratings and Victoria's ratings, which we saved as `v_persons_ratings` in the last step. The option `use = "complete.obs"` means that the correlation only looks at observations where both users rated the film. Then we use `abs` to get the absolute value of the correlation coefficient.

```
v_correlations <- tidy_cr %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(
    pearson = cor(rating, v_persons_ratings, use = "complete.obs"),
    pearson_abs = abs(pearson)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 400 x 6
   user    film                      rating  mean pearson pearson_abs
   <fct>   <chr>                      <int> <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 John    Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      1  3.07  0.277       0.277 
 2 Maria   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      5  2.79  0.493       0.493 
 3 Anton   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope     NA  2.46 -0.185       0.185 
 4 Roger   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope     NA  2.69 -0.307       0.307 
 5 Martina Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      4  3.21  0.0477      0.0477
 6 Ana     Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      2  3.07  0.598       0.598 
 7 Sergi   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope     NA  2.55  0.0364      0.0364
 8 Marc    Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      4  2.83  0.0793      0.0793
 9 Jim     Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      5  3.15 -0.445       0.445 
10 Chris   Star.Wars.IV...A.New.Hope      4  3.18 -0.344       0.344 
# ... with 390 more rows
```

Finally we reduce to the rows that contain films Victoria has not seen, using `filter` and the `%in%` operator. We `group_by` film this time, so the calculation is done per-film. Then, we use `summarise` to calculate the recommendation score using the formula you listed in the question, and add on Victoria's mean. Last of all we sort by rating in descending order using `arrange` and `desc`.

```
v_recommendations <- v_correlations %>%
  filter(film %in% v_films_not_seen) %>%
  group_by(film) %>%
  summarise(
    score = sum((rating - mean) * pearson, na.rm = TRUE) / (sum(pearson_abs) - 1)) %>%
  mutate(score = score + mean(v_persons_ratings, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(desc(score))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  film                     score
  <chr>                    <dbl>
1 The.Matrix                3.79
2 Forrest.Gump              3.51
3 The.Sixth.Sense           3.33
4 Shakespeare.in.Love       3.11
5 Blade.Runner              2.91
6 Saving.Private.Ryan       2.89
7 The.Shawshank.Redemption  2.81
```

### Function

Whew! Now we can just put the above code into a function, replacing all the `v_` objects above with generic ones, and providing `tbl`, `person` and `n` as the arguments. `tbl` is the data of films, users, ratings and user mean ratings, `person` is the person who we want recommendations for, and `n` is the number of recommendations we want. This code is basically the same as above, except I added `head(n)` at the end to return only `n` rows of the recommendation table.

```
top_recs <- function(tbl, person, n){
  films_not_seen <- tbl %>%
    filter(user == person & is.na(rating)) %>%
    extract2("film")
  persons_ratings <- tbl %>%
    filter(user == person) %>%
    extract2("rating")
  correlations <- tbl %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    mutate(
      pearson = cor(rating, persons_ratings, use = "complete.obs"),
      pearson_abs = abs(pearson)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
  recommendations <- correlations %>%
    filter(film %in% films_not_seen) %>%
    group_by(film) %>%
    summarise(
      score = sum((rating - mean) * pearson, na.rm = TRUE) / (sum(pearson_abs) - 1)) %>%
    mutate(score = score + mean(persons_ratings, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    arrange(desc(score)) %>%
    head(n)
}
```

We can test the function with Victoria again and see that it works:

```
top_recs(tidy_cr, "Victoria", 5) %>% print()
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  film                score
  <chr>               <dbl>
1 The.Matrix           3.79
2 Forrest.Gump         3.51
3 The.Sixth.Sense      3.33
4 Shakespeare.in.Love  3.11
5 Blade.Runner         2.91
```

But we can now also get the recommendations for any user, for example 8 recommendations for Bernard:

```
top_recs(tidy_cr, "Bernard", 8) %>% print()
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  film                     score
  <chr>                    <dbl>
1 The.Shawshank.Redemption  3.23
2 Pulp.Fiction              3.17
3 Schindler.s.List          3.11
4 Blade.Runner              2.97
5 Saving.Private.Ryan       2.94
6 Shakespeare.in.Love       2.74
7 Groundhog.Day             2.72
8 Stand.by.Me               2.60
```

### Notes

This is actually an interesting exercise in whether or not you can figure out the tools to do what you want and structure the workflow accordingly. The power in this approach I think is highlighted in that we can now get recommendations for any user. Perhaps more importantly, nothing in this code (I think) is dependent on these particular users or films or ratings. If you have more data, you can just add them to the bottom of `tidy_cr` and the function will still work. If you change your rating formula, you only have to edit a couple lines to update it.

I hope you can step through this and learn more about how to write your own functions in R! Other next steps might be error checking, like showing something informative if you ask for more recommendations than there are or if you type a user's name who isn't in the database. I think it is probably daunting, but `?` is your best friend in R to check what the options for functions are. I definitely didn't know all of this off the top of my head!

Comment: would it not be best to just specify `-user` in the gather statement instead of specifically mentioning film names as that won't work if more are added.

Comment: yep, will add that! the gather part will be a bit manual anyway though since user colname may also change with different datasets.

Comment: Holy *** man, I really appreciate all your help, I know some tidy so I was able to understand. I am definitely not at the level of actually doing this myself but I was able to understand it all.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you so much!